# Am I applying the sandwich theorem correctly?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a function $f(x)$ that is bounded by $x$ and $y(x)$ more precisely, 
$$x>f(x) >y(x) $$ where $y(x) $ is increasing in $x$.

When $x \rightarrow \infty $, Can I say that $f(x) \rightarrow \infty$ therefore $f(x) =x$ when $x$ is sufficiently large enough? Or at least $f(x) $ converges to $x$?

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider functions defined on $\Bbb R_{>0}$. No, because $y$ could be something like $y(x) =- 1/x$. It is increasing, but $\lim_{x \to +\infty} y(x) = 0$. If you take $f(x) = 0$ for all $x > 0$, then: $$x > 0 > -\frac{1}{x}, \quad \forall\,x > 0,$$ but $\lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x) \neq +\infty.$

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. Here is a counter-example:
$$
x>\sqrt{x}>\sqrt[3]{x}, \qquad x>1,
$$ take
$$
f(x)=\sqrt{x}, \qquad y(x)=\sqrt[3]{x},
$$ you have
 $$
\lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x)=+\infty.
$$ and $$
f(x)\neq x, \qquad x>1.
$$